# Optimization calculated property Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a model:

```
public class Genre : DbObject
{
    public string GenreName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();

    public virtual int BooksCount => Books.Count;
}
```

As I understand that each time the `BooksCount`  will be a request to the database to count the number of objects in the collection of `Books`. Maybe there is some approach to property `BooksCount` changed in the database only when the collection changed?